# Finding meaningful boundaries between two continuous variables in R

Tags: r, clustering, svm, discriminant-analysis, kruskal-wallis-test

To find the relationship between two columns of the iris dataset, I am performing kruskal.test and p.value shows a meaningful relationship between these two columns.

```
data(iris)
kruskal.test(iris$Petal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width)
```

Here are the results:

```
    Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  iris$Petal.Length and iris$Sepal.Width
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 41.827, df = 22, p-value = 0.00656
```

The Scatter plot also shows some sort of relationship.

```
plot(iris$Petal.Length, iris$Petal.Width)
```

[image]

To find the meaningful boundaries of these two variables, I ran pairwise.wilcox.test test, but for this test to work, one of the variables needs to be categorical. If I pass both continuous variables to it, then the results are not as expected.

```
pairwise.wilcox.test(x = iris$Petal.Length, g = iris$Petal.Width, p.adjust.method = "BH")
```

As an output, I need a clear cut point where these two variables have some sort of relationship and where this relationship ends (As shown through the red line in the attached image above)

I am not sure if there is any statistical test or another programming technique to find these boundaries.

e.g. manually I can do something like this to mark boundaries -

```
setDT(iris)[, relationship := ifelse(Petal.Length > 3 & Sepal.Width < 3.5, 1, 0)]
```

But, is there a test to find such boundaries?

Thanks, Saurabh

Comment: "Test" and "find" are different objectives, which is confusing.  It sounds like you are looking for something like linear discriminant analysis (LDA) or support vector machines (SVM) or even any kind of cluster analysis: searches for any of these on our site will yield a lot of useful suggestions.

Comment: I think LDA is for parametric data. Is there a similar test for non-parametric data?

Comment: First, there's no such thing as "parametric data:" the term "parametric" applies to models, not data.  Second, LDA uses a hugely flexible model that applies to almost any data.  Third, the other kinds of procedures I mentioned can perform the same kind of discrimination functions you are looking for.